# Closed socket still in LISTENING and CLOSE_WAIT state after it is closed (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, ports

I am opening sockets on my localhost to receive connections from another virtual machine. I want to be able to close the socket/connection when I hit a button, however, even though the socket is closed, it is still in listening/close_wait state.

My code is the following:

```
def screen_cast(self, emulator_identifier, mode, server_ip, server_port, username):
    global tcp_server_mode_dict
    logging.info('Processing screen cast request on emulator ' + emulator_identifier)
    try:
        # change port so that there's a different one used for every vm ip
        server_port = str(int(server_port) + int(emulator_identifier.split('.')[3].split(':')[0]))
        if mode == "on":
            args = [self.__ADB_EXE, "-s", emulator_identifier, "shell", "am", "startservice", "-a", server_ip + ":" + server_port, "com.conti.its.philipp.screener/.StartScreening"]
            tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier] = "on"
            logging.info('Starting screencast')
        elif mode == "off":
            args = [self.__ADB_EXE, "-s", emulator_identifier, "shell", "am","force-stop", "com.conti.its.philipp.screener"]
            tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier] = "off"
            logging.info('Stopping screencast')
        if (mode in ["on", "off"]):
            sp.call(args)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.screen_cast_service, args=[server_ip, server_port, emulator_identifier, username])
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
        else:
            return 'failed'
        return tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier]
    except:
        logging.exception('Invoking screencast on mode ' + mode)
        return 'failed'

def screen_cast_service(self, server_ip, server_port, emulator_identifier, username):
    global tcp_server_mode_dict
    logging.info('Handling screen cast service. Status: ' + tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier])
    logging.info('Emulator IP: ' + emulator_identifier + ', Port: ' + server_port)
    username_ext = username + "/"
    try:
        # create the dir to store the screenshot if not existing
        if not os.path.exists(settings.DWD_DIR + username + "/screen/"):
            os.makedirs(settings.DWD_DIR + username + "/screen/")

        if not emulator_identifier in tcp_sockets:
            s = socket.socket()
            tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier] = s 

        if tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier] == "on":
            tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            ADDR = (server_ip, int(server_port))

            tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier].bind(ADDR)
            tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier].listen(10)

            while (tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier] == "on"):

                ss, address = tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier].accept()
                logging.info("Got Connection from: " + address[0])

                with open(settings.DWD_DIR + username + "/screen/" + 'screen.png', 'wb') as f:
                    while True:
                        data = ss.recv(1024)
                        if not data:
                            break
                        f.write(data)

        elif tcp_server_mode_dict[emulator_identifier] == "off":
            tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier].close()
            del tcp_sockets[emulator_identifier]

    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('ScreenCast Server')
```

When I check for open ports, the following shows up:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :9448
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Python    17930 philipp   12u  IPv4 0x6c021ad25d0cb947      0t0  TCP 192.168.56.1:9448 (LISTEN)
Python    17930 philipp   14u  IPv4 0x6c021ad2535e9947      0t0  TCP 192.168.56.1:9448->192.168.56.1:52964 (CLOSE_WAIT)
VBoxHeadl 17963 philipp   35u  IPv4 0x6c021ad26bfaa567      0t0  TCP 192.168.56.1:52964->192.168.56.1:9448 (FIN_WAIT_2)
```

This doesn't throw an error or anything but when I wan't to turn the service back on again and create another socket, I get an error that the address is already used.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first one is the server socket. The other two show both ends of a single connection that is in the process of closing.

Comment: why is the server socket still listening although I closed it then? And can I close the other connections faster, since I want to be able to turn the service on and off which is not possible as the address is still used.

Comment: Clearly your code is _not_ closing the server socket, and one side of the client connection is hanging on as well.  You need to set breakpoints in the debugger to see why the server socket is not being closed.

Comment: The structure of the code looks pretty messed up.  In `screen_cast` you are starting a new independent thread regardless of whether the mode is `on` or `off`.  Also, you should need only ONE server socket.  On each `accept` you receive a new socket to handle that specific connection.  It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve or why the code is structured the way it is.  And finally, questions of the form "here's my code, please help debug it" are off-topic unless you provide A LOT more detail on what you've already done.  I suspect a complete rewrite will be needed.

Comment: I have several Android emulators running in the background. For each of them, I have one server socket that listens to a specific emulator. Each emulator has a service that is started which creates a socket, sends a screenshot over the socket to the server and then closes the socket again. Since I have multiple emulators, I used multiple server sockets since each server socket accepts multiple sockets that are opened by the Android service